# Deployed laravel app, only homepage working

Tags: html, laravel, .htaccess, production-environment

I have recently finished a website for a customer, the site works great locally. Currently only the homepage is working. However all links return a 500 server  error.

This is 1and1, and I haven't heard many good things about it.
Currently I have the laravel folders for my app within a folder called webapp.
the domain name points to webapp/public.
I have also added the following line to my htaccess to get it to work

```
RewriteRule ^ /home.php [L]
```

which works for the homepage. I don't know much about the htaccess file, so I've messed around with a few other options such as

```
RewriteRule ^ /folios.php [L]
```

as well which is one of the links in my site, however this doesn't work.

My routes currently work like this

```
Route::get('/folios', 'AlbumsController@index');
```

However they return 500 server error

Comment: If you have got an error 500 read a log laravel or apache.

Answer (score 2):

Change the line in the ".htaccess" file in the root folder from  `RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]` to
`RewriteRule ^ /index.php [L]`

Comment: Thank you, that actually worked for me! (Laravel 10)

Answer (score 0):

My suspicion is that you need to update the paths contained within public/index.php

Check out this article for instructions: https://medium.com/@Bohr/deploy-laravel-application-on-shared-hosting-godaddy-953758dc57ac

Comment: I tried changing the paths like it says on the link provided, however still nothing has changed unfortunately

Comment: I instead get the error: Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/homepages/12/d550837192/htdocs/webapp/public/../webapp/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php7.3') in /homepages/12/d550837192/htdocs/webapp/public/index.php on line 24

Answer (score 0):

Did you run composer install on the server or copy out the vendor directory? You may also want to check that your htaccess file in the public directory contains the directives that are required (https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/public/.htaccess).

Answer (score 0):

I did not realize that the server generated a new .htaccess file within the /webapp/ folder where I pointed the domain; I was editing the wrong .htaccess file